# Reading output from USB-to-Serial converter

Tags: bash, serial-port, tty

I created a bash script to randomize some number, then send it to > /dev/ttyUSB0. This is a converter (USB to serial, RS-232) that is plugged through the notebook USB.
Right now, my only wish is to see these random numbers (sent from one terminal) on some other terminal (same PC). I've already tried using screen, cat, minicom, and other internet-favorites, but with no success.

Right now, when I run the random-number script (while other terminal is trying to read the output from the port), the "best" answer is saying that the ttyUSB0 is unavailable at the moment.

Appreciate your help,
Regards;

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
number=$RANDOM
echo $number >/dev/ttyUSB0
echo $number
sleep 4
done
```

I expected to see the random numbers through other terminal. Instead, I'm reading different kind of errors.

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending your data to the devcice registered by the USB-to-serial device driver, rather than direct to the USB port. There could be any number of devices plugged into a hub on the port.

Comment: It makes sense, but the situation is: I have a satellital device, and it has it's own software to work with the data flow. I will not have access to this software until 2 weeks from now.
Given the situation, my mission now is to master the path up until the usb-to-serial converter, since it's the last spot before the data will enter my satellital device.

Thank you!

Comment: If you have another USB-to-RS232 adapter, then a null-modem connection would allow you to receive whatever you send out on the first adapter.  A loopback could also be used, but is really just a simple test that could confuse you (e.g. it's just like echoing).  *"Instead, I'm reading different kind of errors"* -- Your summation is inadequate to prompt any advice.

Comment: The first and most persistent error was the absence of "printing" the received data. I've got a few more after trying to mess with modemmanager (callback errors). I agree with you, and I'm getting to the point where I think I need the device's software. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I could do it quite simply with minicom now. After resetting parameters, I reconfigured minicom (minicom -s). After starting the minicom (to /dev/ttyUSB0) in one terminal, I ran my script in another terminal (that echos random numbers to /dev/ttyUSB0) and could finally receive all data.